# show that $|\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z-\frac{3}{2}}|\le4\pi$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

if $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\mapsto\Bbb C,\quad \gamma(t)=1+e^{it}$ then show that $|\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z-\frac{3}{2}}|\le4\pi$ (without computing)

I tried : 
    $ |\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z-\frac{3}{2}}| \le \int_\gamma|\frac{1}{z-\frac{3}{2}}|dz$  and $ |z-\frac{3}{2}|\ge||z|-\frac{3}{2}|$ we should find its max value$  .\quad$
 $z=\gamma(t)=1+e^{it} $ then we can say $x(t)=1+cost\quad and\quad y(t)=isint$ so we have $
(x-1)^2+y^2=1 $ circle. how can we continue? $max{|z|}=1$ so $||z|-\frac{3}{2}|\le |1-\frac{3}{2}| \quad =\frac{1}{2}? $

edit :
 $||z|-\frac{3}{2}|\le |1-\frac{3}{2}|  =\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{|z-\frac{3}{2}|}\le2\Rightarrow \int_c\frac{1}{|z-\frac{3}{2}|}dz\le\int_c2dz=4\pi \Rightarrow  |\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z-\frac{3}{2}}|\le4\pi $

Comment: Does using Cauchy's integral formula count as computing?

Answer (score 1):

Do this and you will find your way:

1. Your $z$ in the integral varies on $\gamma$.
2. $\gamma$ is a circle of radius 1, with center $z=1$.
3. Find the point on the circle $\gamma$, that is closest to $z=3/2$. Note that that point maximize $$|f(z)|= \frac{1}{|z-3/2|}$$

Comment: is it now correct? Could you check my edit on the quest. please?

Comment: No, your answer is still not correct, for example the max value of $|z|$ is not 1. See 1. in my post. Also, you should ask your self why you want to maximize $|z|$.

Answer (score 1):

Without replacing $z$ with $|z|$ you need to find the minimal value of $|e^{it}-1/2|$ which is $1/2$ (on the unit circle $1$ is closest to 1/2). The length of your path is $2\pi$ so the integral is smaller than $\pi$.

Comment: ...you need to find the MINIMAL (not maximal) value of |eit−3/2| (not |eit-1/2|...

Comment: @Did: Oops, thank you, although I think we are looking for the minimal value of $|e^{it}-1/2|$ because the path maps $t$ to $1+e^{it}$.

Comment: Yes, eit-1/2, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Another short answer goes "By the Argument principle we have...".